# How can I open simultaneously 2 client socket connections with GSM shield?

Tags: arduino-uno, shields, gsm

How can I open simultaneously two socket connections with a GSM shield?

It seems that when I try to open the second connection, it is not opened, and additionally the first connection is closed.

Code:

```
#include <GSM.h>

#define PINNUMBER      ""
#define GPRS_APN       "sm2ms.movilforum.es"
#define GPRS_LOGIN     ""   
#define GPRS_PASSWORD  ""

#define SERVER "www.abv.bg"    // some server
#define PORT   80              // some port

static GSM gsm;
static GPRS gprs;
static GSMClient clientControl;    // first connection
static GSMClient clientData;       // second connection

void setup()
{
    // initialize serial communications
    Serial.begin(9600);

    Serial.println("GSM not initialized");

    while (true)
    {
        if (gsm.begin(PINNUMBER) == GSM_READY)
        {
            Serial.println("GSM initialized");

            while (true)
            {
                GSM3_NetworkStatus_t eErrorCode;

                delay(1000);

                eErrorCode = gprs.attachGPRS(GPRS_APN, GPRS_LOGIN, GPRS_PASSWORD);
                if (eErrorCode == GPRS_READY)
                {
                    Serial.println("GPRS initialized");

                    return;
                }
                Serial.print("Not connected to GPRS, error code = ");
                Serial.println(eErrorCode, 1);
            }
        }

        Serial.println("Not connected to GSM");
        delay(1000);
    }
}

void loop()
{
    delay(1000);

    Serial.println((clientControl.connect(SERVER, PORT))
                   ? ("Connected") : ("Couldn't connect"));

    delay(1000);

    Serial.println((clientData.connect(SERVER, PORT))
                   ? ("Second connection succeeded") 
                   : ("Second connection failed"));

    Serial.println("Do something here");

    // close the stuff here!!!
    for (;;);
}
```

The serial dumps:

```
GSM not initialized
GSM initialized
GPRS initialized
Connected
Second connection failed
Do something here
```

With other clients I don't have problem supporting two simultaneous connections. Here the first connection succeeds, the second fails.

Regards,
Boyan

Comment: Could you post the code you are using to create the connections?

Comment: Additionally, it seems to not matter which exactly the server is. The same happens also with other active servers/ports.

Comment: It seems like you cannot open a new one because it is already open, you either need to make a new instance or close the old first.

Comment: First, clientControl and clientData are already two different instances. Secondly, I cannot close the control connection. I need them both open simultaneously. If I close the control connection, everything will end. If I don't open data connection, I cannot send data. Therefore I need them both.

Comment: Could you give us a copy paste of the serial log ?

Comment: Serial log added.